# SQL Nested Query and NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine you have a table called USERS and it contains two fields,

1. User_name -
2. User_Friends  -

The question then is how do you find the the top two users that have the most friends but are not connected with each other?

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT user_name, 
       count(user_friends),
FROM users
GROUP BY user_name
ORDER BY count(user_friends) DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

--> This I think will give the top two users with most connections. But how/where do I add in the WHERE condition to check if the users are in each others friends list? I figure there is some nested query that is needed here?

Many thanks!

Comment: "A string field that contains all the users connections" --- this is the point when it started being wrong. Check for one-to-many and many-to-many to learn how to store relations in RDBMS.

Comment: Can you show what data is stored in the User_friends column?

Comment: Sorry my wording is a little poor

Comment: The only thing this will give you is a syntax error :-( ... See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query